# Provide lazy_static static ref with lifetimes

Tags: rust

Is it possible to provide a lazy static with lifetime args?

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static; //lazy_static = "1.4.0"

enum MyEnum<'a>{
    Name(&'a str)
}

lazy_static! {
    static ref STATIC_ENUM: Mutex<MyEnum<'a>> = Mutex::new(MyEnum::Name("some name"));
}
```

gives:

```
error[E0261]: use of undeclared lifetime name `'a`
    static ref STATIC_ENUM: Mutex<MyEnum<'a>> = Mutex::new(MyEnum::Name("some name"));
                                           ^^ undeclared lifetime
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but the only lifetime you can use for the value of *any* `static` variable (lazy or not) is the `'static` lifetime.

```rust
lazy_static! {
    static ref STATIC_ENUM: Mutex<MyEnum<'static>> = Mutex::new(MyEnum::Name("some name"));
}
```

This may present a problem if you want to put in an `&str` that is not a literal (or deliberately leaked). If you need to do that, *probably* you should not be using a reference at all, but an owned `String`, at which point your enum no longer needs a lifetime parameter:

```rust
enum MyEnum {
    Name(String),
}
```

Also, consider using [`once_cell::sync::Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/1.8.0/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html) instead of `lazy_static::lazy_static`. It won't give you any particular advantage here, but it doesn't use a macro so it doesn't hide things like the actual type of the `static`.